# Use Author Ids or Names to echo different output inside loop

Tags: custom-post-types, author, loop, id

Is there a way to use the author ids (or names) to echo different output for different authors (in this case author id 7 and author admin? I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
    ?php if (get_the_author_meta(7)) {echo '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >'; 
     echo'<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Thumbnail", true);?>'; echo '</a>';} else {
    echo '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Thumbnail", true);?>"/></a>';  } ?><?php  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('ID') == 7) : ?>
    Do something for user with ID 7.
<?php else : ?>
    Do something for anybody else.
<?php  endif; ?>
```

Try this, where 7 is the ID of the user.